# To set Time period in shell script

Tags: shell, cron

I have requirement to set time period in the variable TP0. One time period in such a way that it contains transaction where flag is true from db.

I can get the transaction from db "where flag = true" query. But I need to set the time period to get those transactions from start and end time in variable TP0.

```
Start_Time=2017-08-28 22:59:09.28
End_Time  =2017-08-28 23:08:58.909
```

Please guide me to do this in shell script. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If this is something to do with a database, it has some tags missing.

Comment: @Mark Setchell Yes, Its related to db to fetch the particular time period transaction. We have Start_Time and End_Time parameter as the argument(input) to pass for executing the shell script. Now the requirement is "Set parameters Start_Time and End_Time to TP0 interval limits"